# How to group the css selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css, lit

```
:host([aspect-ratio='square']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-square);
    }
    :host([aspect-ratio='landscape']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-landscape);
    }
    :host([aspect-ratio='portrait']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-portrait);
    }
    :host([aspect-ratio='widescreen']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-widescreen);
    }
    :host([aspect-ratio='ultrawide']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-ultrawide);
    }
    :host([aspect-ratio='golden']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-golden);
    }
```

How can I make it to a single line? by reducing the duplicates of this code

Comment: Your method is probably wrong, there is no advantage here of using css var() . `:host([aspect-ratio]) img {aspect-ratio: var(--ratio); }` should be your selector, while the value of --ratio is set ealier in your code

Comment: @G-Cyrillus they would still need to have somewhere a long list of `[aspect-ratio="AAAA"] { --ratio: var(--ratio-AAAA) } [aspect-ratio="AAAA"] { --ratio: var(--ratio-BBBB) }`. That would just shave a few characters.

Comment: @Kaiido nop, if this is so, then it is also a misusue of css var() . ( when i mean *earlier in your code*  doesn't mean earlier in the css , he obviously uses javascript, and it's probably there that the var() can be applied on the fly .  --ratio , not --ratio-x

Comment: That sounds like a very strong opinion on your side from the very little we know about the current situation. We don't know how they do compose these `--ratio-XXX` and they may very well need that inter-step. Regarding your edit, how do you know they use JS at all? This file may very well just be one of multiple modules, and the actual values are set in a parent.

Comment: @indeed, we are missing parts of the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can reasonably do this with a single line.

You could do simplify it with Sass/Scss:

```
$ratios: "square", "landscape", "portrait", "widescreen", "ultrawide", "golden";

@each $ratio in $ratios {
    :host([aspect-ratio='#{$ratio}']) img {
      aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-#{$ratio});
    }
}
```

Which generates the CSS:

```css
:host([aspect-ratio='square']) img {
    aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-square);
}

:host([aspect-ratio='landscape']) img {
    aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-landscape);
}

:host([aspect-ratio='portrait']) img {
    aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-portrait);
}

:host([aspect-ratio='widescreen']) img {
    aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-widescreen);
}

:host([aspect-ratio='ultrawide']) img {
    aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-ultrawide);
}

:host([aspect-ratio='golden']) img {
    aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-golden);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any CSS only solution here. You'd basically need to be able to read the content of the attribute (`attr()` should be able to do that), and then use it to compose a new CSS variable. This last step is more problematic, I don't think there is any way to compose strings in CSS and pass them to a func like `var()`.

I would have hoped for the new [`@property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property) rule to allow us to do something around that, but when I tried to reference `var(--css-var)` values as [`syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@property/syntax) that simply failed (with no real surprises I must admit). And even if that did work, I'm not sure the `attr()` could have been used there either. `attr()` produces `<string>` and I don't think there is a way to convert a `<string>` to a variable name.

So the best I can think of as a CSS+HTML only solution is to modify your HTML code so that instead of doing

```html
<my-elem aspect-ratio="square">content</my-elem>
```

You do

```html
<my-elem style="--ratio:var(--ratio-square)">content</my-elem>
```

As you can see, that's a bit more character but stays relatively readable, and then your CSS can become

```
:host([style*="--ratio:"]) img { aspect-ratio: var(--ratio) }
```

```js
class MyElem extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    const img = new Image();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(img);

    style.textContent = `
img { width: 150px; border: 1px solid; }
:host([style*="--ratio:"]) img {
  aspect-ratio: var(--ratio);
}    
`;
  }
}
customElements.define("my-elem", MyElem);
```

```css
:root {
  --ratio-square: 1/1;
  --ratio-landscape: 4/3;
  --ratio-golden: 1/1.618;
}
```

```html
<my-elem style="--ratio:var(--ratio-square)"></my-elem>
<my-elem style="--ratio:var(--ratio-landscape)"></my-elem>
<my-elem style="--ratio:var(--ratio-golden)"></my-elem>
```

But given that you are in a ShadowDOM, you can actually keep that attribute and use your CustomElement's constructor to set the proper CSS variable at construct:

```js
class MyElem extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    const img = new Image();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
    shadowRoot.appendChild(img);
    const ratio = this.getAttribute("aspect-ratio");
    style.textContent = `
img { width: 150px; border: 1px solid; }
:host([aspect-ratio]) img {
  aspect-ratio: var(--ratio-${ratio});
}    
`;
  }
}
customElements.define("my-elem", MyElem);
```

```css
:root {
  --ratio-square: 1/1;
  --ratio-landscape: 4/3;
  --ratio-golden: 1/1.618;
}
```

```html
<my-elem aspect-ratio="square"></my-elem>
<my-elem aspect-ratio="landscape"></my-elem>
<my-elem aspect-ratio="golden"></my-elem>
```